# How to find the multiple occurrence spacial character in the given string?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
string text = "{hello|{hi}} {world}";
```

Actually i want the '{' and  '}' each occurrence position from the given string

Please help me...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Regex.Matches. It will search all strings which are splitted by '|' in sentence.
You can add all strings with their indices to Dictioanry.

```
  string pattern = "{|}";
  string text = "{hello|{hi}} {world}";
  Dictionary<int, string> indeces = new Dictionary<int, string>();
  foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, pattern))
  {
       indeces.Add(match.Index, match.Value);
  }
```

Result is:

```
0-{
7-{
10-}
11-}
13-{
19-}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "{hello|{hi}} {world}";
var indexes = str.ToCharArray()
             .Select((x,index) => new {x, index})
             .Where(i => i.x=='{' ||i.x=='}')
             .Select(p=>p.index);
```

result

```
0 
7 
10 
11 
13 
19
```

Comment: +1 Shortest posible way to do this..!

Comment: This is consuming more time... any way thanks much !

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex of make an function that will loop through you chars

Example 1

```
string text = "{hello|{hi}} {world}";
var indexes = new List<int>();
var ItemRegex = new Regex("[{}]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
foreach (Match ItemMatch in ItemRegex.Matches(text))
{
    indexes.Add(ItemMatch.Index);
}
```

Example 2 (the linq way)

```
string text = "{hello|{hi}} {world}";

var itemRegex = new Regex("[{}]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var matches = itemRegex.Matches(text).Cast<Match>();
var indexes = matches.Select(i => i.Index);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create two Lists 
`List<int> opening 
                 List<int> closing`

Then scan the string in for int i  = 0; i < string.length -1;i++.
compare each char with opening or closing bracket.
like if chr == '{' then put counter i into the corresponding list.

After the entire string You should have the positions opening and closing brackets in the corresponding list.

Did that help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can *enumerate* the occurences:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> FindOccurences(String value, params Char[] toFind) {
  if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) && (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, toFind)))       
    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i) 
      if (toFind.Contains(value[i]))
        yield return i;
}

...

String text = "{hello|{hi}} {world}";

foreach(int index in FindOccurences(text, '{', '}')) {
  ...
}
```